# Simple HTML DOM - Find table with width="327"

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Using Simple HTML DOM, how to find `<table>` that has `width="327"` ?

For example:

```
<table width="327" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
```

Code

```
$html = $html->find('table', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple HTML DOM finds on base of attribute with syntax `[attribute=value]`

```
$html = $html->find('table[width=327]', 0);
```